# How to set a value for DateTimePicker control?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DateTimePicker control in form1. I want to set its value in that control from a `nvarchar(50)` BirthDate field of an Employee table in my DB.

```
public string EmpBirthDate
{ 
    get { return dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value.ToString(); }
    set { dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

But, I get this error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker' does not contain a definition
>       for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument
>       of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker' could be found (are you
>       missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why is your `BirthDate` field an `nvarchar(50)` in the first place? Why would you keep it as text rather than as a date-based type?

Comment: Note that the error message you posted says 'value' (lower case v), and the property is actually `Value` (upper case V).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, DateTimePicker has a property named 'Value' with a capital V, not lower case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx